# How to mount sparseimage permanently at specific mount point?

Tags: macos, mac, mount, disk-image

I have a read/write image that needs to be mounted at a specific location, how can I have it mounted on bootup at that location? Not necessarily for my user but maybe the whole system? My mount point is `/.000` if that gives a good idea as to where I want it mounted.

Answer (score 0):

Simply drag the mounted image to Login Items at Users & Groups in system preferences, this will mount the disk as soon as the user is logged in.

Comment: This does not specify a mount path and will mount to /Volumes right?

Comment: This simply mounts it as if u have clicked the .sparsebundle file in the Finder, if you want specific  mount points you should create a command that will run at login/boot to mount the disk.

Comment: I got a launchd command to work, but I don't what I did to make it finally work. I think I had to invoke hdiutil by its full path, but I'm not sure.